# Scoping of environment variables when using Jupyter cell magics

Tags: scope, jupyter-notebook

I would like to understand how variable scoping works in Jupyter notebooks.

When I create a *bash* notebook with two cells, environment variables that are exported are visible across cell boundaries:

In [1]:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/samplepath
```

In [2]:

```
echo $PATH
```

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/myuser/samplepath`

But if I create a *Python* notebook and use cell magics to achieve the same result, variables do not seem to be visible across cell boundaries any more:

In [1]:

```
%%script bash
export PATH=$PATH:~/samplepath
```

In [2]:

```
%%script bash
echo $PATH
```

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

This behaviour stays the same for different magics (i.e., using an exclamation mark in front of echo instead of the script magic gives the same result).

So, I'd like to understand what the scoping rules are in this case, and how I can make `export` truly export variables so that they are visible in the entire notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Jupyter notebook *(as in your second example)*, the shell commands in the notebook are executed in a temporary subshell i.e. every command you write using `!` (or under `%%bash`) runs in a different subprocess.

A good description from [this blog post](http://mmcdan.github.io/posts/interacting-with-the-shell-via-jupyter-notebook/) is:

> The Jupyter Notebook shell commands are executed in a shell that is a subprocess of the shell running the notebook. Because of this, changes in environmental variables in the child (cell) shell will not be reflected in the parent (notebook) shell.

In[1]:

```
%%bash 
export var="5"
echo $var
```

```
5
```

In[2]:

```
%%bash
echo $var
```

*No output*

This is the very reason why the commands like `!cd /path/` can't be used to navigate the file system. Check [another blog post](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Shell-Related-Magic-Commands) on this.

While the case is different with *bash notebook*, where everything is executed in a single shell.

**Solution:**

If you want to export a variable to environment shell variables, then you can use [`%env`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-env) magic function as follows:

In[3]:

```
%env var "5"
```

In[4]:

```
%env var
```

In[5]:

```
%%bash
echo $var
```

Output of In[4] and In[5]:

```
'"5"'
```

*Note:* But beware, dont't do `%env PATH=$PATH:~/samplepath` as it'll simply replace the PATH variable thus causing problems. The above solution is recommended for non-system variables only. Nevertheless, you can edit `.bashrc` to universally change the `PATH` variable.

Comment: how do I use them together with %%bash?