# How can I concat envvars in Jupyter notebooks using %env

Tags: jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, virtualenv, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there any strategy for combining two or more envvars without having to use Python code? I'm trying to do something like this.

```sh
%env INFLUXDB_VERSION 1.7.7
%env INFLUXDB_PATH=influxdb-${INFLUXDB_VERSION}
```

The strategy below works, but it has a cell scope (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745979/scoping-of-environment-variables-when-using-jupyter-cell-magics)).

```sh
%%bash
export INFLUXDB_VERSION="1.7.7"
export INFLUXDB_PATH="influxdb-${INFLUXDB_VERSION}"
echo $INFLUXDB_PATH
```

Thanks in advance!